# Elixir count number of occurences when condition is satisfied

Tags: enums, elixir

I try to do the following thing in Elixir that can be achieved in Python:

```
sum = 0
for elem in list:
  if elem >= 5:
    sum += 1
```

For example: I want to return the number `3` given the list `[0, 5, 8, 3, 10]`

This is what I did in Elixir (this is not working yet):

```
    cond do
          Enum.empty?(list) -> 0
          length(list) == 1 -> if List.first(list) >= 5 do 1 else 0 end
          true -> 
            Enum.reduce(list, 0, fn x, acc -> if x >= 5 do acc + 1 end end)
          end
    end
```

I get the following error: `** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression: nil + 1`

Edit:

Found it!
The problem was that I didn't return any value when x < 5, resulting of no value passed to `acc` therefore `acc` was `nil`. This code below works:

```
cond do
      Enum.empty?(list) -> 0
      length(list) == 1 -> if List.first(list) >= 5 do 1 else 0 end
      true -> 
        Enum.reduce(list, 0, fn x, acc -> if x >= 5 do acc + 1 else acc + 0 end end)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the reduce function, you forgot to tell what to do when the number is 5 or less:

```
list = [0, 5, 8, 3, 10]
Enum.reduce(list, 0, fn num, acc -> if num >= 5, do: acc + 1, else: acc end)
```

And even simpler with [`Enum.count/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#count/2):

```
Enum.count(list, & &1 >= 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, this can also be done via a fold function.  Like this:

```
list = [0, 5, 8, 3, 10]
List.foldl(list, 0, fn num, acc -> if num >=5, do: acc+1, else: acc end)
```

Typically a fold is used for some type of summation of a list for example:

```
List.foldl(list, 0, fn num, acc -> num + acc end)
# 26
```

Or

```
List.foldl(["a","b","c"], "", fn char, string -> string <> char end)
# "abc"
```

but it doesn't have to be.  I cannot recall if reduce is considered a more general form of a fold or the other way around.  As I say, I post this one for sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

[`Enum.count/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.1/Enum.html#count/2) is the go-to solution:

```elixir
Enum.count(list, fn elem -> elem >= 5 end)
```

---

You can also do it without using any modules by using a [comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.1/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-the-reduce-option):

```elixir
for elem <- list, elem >= 5, reduce: 0 do
  acc -> acc + 1
end
```

Or with recursion:

```elixir
def count([]), do: 0
def count([elem | rest]) when elem >= 5, do: 1 + count(rest)
def count([_elem | rest]), do: count(rest)
```